# Are there any advantages to wrapping synchronous code in a Javascript promise?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, promise

I understand that promises makes it easier to work with asynchronous code instead of using callback functions, but I'm not so clear about the advantages of using them for purely synchronous code.

Let's say I have a function that performs an expensive calculation that takes 5 seconds to complete (not asynchronous, just pure calculations). Because promises will run on the same thread as the single JS thread, are there any advantages to doing this:

```
expensiveFunction() {
  // expensive function that takes 5 seconds to complete
}

expensiveFunction();
doSomethingAfterwards();
```

instead of this:

```
expensiveFunctionPromise() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    // expensive function that takes 5 seconds to complete
    resolve();
  }
}

expensiveFunction().then(doSomethingAfterwards);
```

**Edit**: I put together a jsfiddle that seems to show no difference between the two:

https://jsfiddle.net/nu1wj681/

The sync version takes around 3 seconds per loop for a total of 6 seconds, whereas the promise/async version takes 6 seconds per loop, but the total time is still 6 seconds, which indicates to me that they're both running in parallel, but also on the same thread.

Comment: No. It just complicates your code. The only reason you might want to do this is if the function _might_ become asynchronous at one point.

Comment: If you have expensive synchronous code, you should be looking into [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Managing the web workers may be a good reason to use promises.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have precisely that concern. After a fetch, I am chaining 3 functions: one asynchronous request (promise) then one synchronous, but quite long, that I intent to bring to web worker, when I will be smart enough to do that ... plus another synchronous function (basically a view), which I prefer to place in a next 'then' for better code readability. Therefore, I want to prepare the future by "promisifying" my first synchronous function, making it "thenable". Does it make sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promised are designed to help you manage asynchronous code and thus - at least as far as I know - do not have any advantages when used for synchronous processing. Also the promise itself is not asynchronous and thus sync code within the promise will still be executed sync.
In this context also take a look at the first sentence of the "documentation":

> The Promise object is used for deferred and asynchronous computations.
>   A Promise represents an operation that hasn't completed yet, but is
>   expected in the future.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Synchronous code just won't complete in the future.

If you want to execute the "expensive function" asynchronous and not on the main thread you may want to take a look at "web workers". Using promises in combination with web workers is a nice thing.